# Display corresponding content in textbox when title in the list box is selected.(MVVM WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have created a database where I stored a "title" and "content" of the book. In the program, the title is stored in the listbox and when I populate the list I should be able to display the corresponding "content" in the textbox when the  "title" in the list is clicked. I was able to do this in Windows Forms Application without any issues, but I am trying to implement this on WPF using the MVVM pattern. I am learning and hope to get some advice from you guys. Below is what I have so far.

XAML portion:

```
<Grid>
<ListBox x:Name="UserList" ItemsSource="{Binding UserEntry}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="323" Margin="18,16,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Width="225" />
<TextBox x:Name="BookTextBox" Text="{Binding BookList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="374" Margin="258,16,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"
         VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="292" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  />
<Button x:Name="NewButton" Content="New" Command="{Binding NewCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="18,344,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="30" />
<Button x:Name="List" Content="List" Command="{Binding ListCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding CanClose}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="93,344,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="30" />
<Button x:Name="Delete" Content="Delete" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="168,344,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="30" />
```

View model

```
private BookContext Context;
        private readonly ObservableCollection<string> _userEntry = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        private string _selectedIndex;
        private string _content;
        private bool mystate = true;
        public ICommand NewCommand
        {
            get { return new DelegateCommand(OpenNewWindow); }
        }

        public ICommand ListCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new DelegateCommand(ListEntry);

            }
            set { ListCommand.CanExecute(mystate); }

        }

        public IEnumerable<string> UserEntry
        {
            get { return _userEntry; }
        }
        public void OpenNewWindow()
        {
            MainWindow mainwin = new MainWindow();
            mainwin.Hide();
            Create create = new Create();
            mainwin.Content = create;
            mainwin.Show();
        }

        public void ListEntry()
        {

            Context = new BookContext();
            var query = from b in Context.BookModels
                orderby b.BookId
                select b;
            foreach (var q in query)
            {
                _userEntry.Add(q.Title);
            }



        }

        public string BookList
        {
            get { return _content; }
            set { _content = value; }
        }

        public string SelectedIndex
        {
            get { return _selectedIndex; }
            set
            {
                if (_selectedIndex == value)
                {
                    var query = from b in Context.BookModels
                        where b.Title == _selectedIndex
                        select b;
                    foreach (var q in query)
                    {
                        _content = q.Content;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

I tried to use the SelectIndex way but did not work. I am able to populate the contents in the listbox but when I select any item on the list box, the corresponding content does not appear in the textbox. Please, advice me for any correction or if you need further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code.

```
 <StackPanel>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Books}" x:Name="ListBoxBooks" DisplayMemberPath="Title"></ListBox>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=ListBoxBooks,Path=SelectedItem.Content}"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new BookViewModel();
    }
}

public class BookViewModel
{
    public List<BookModel> Books { get; set; }

    public BookViewModel()
    {
        Books = new List<BookModel>()
        {
            new BookModel() {Title = "Title 1", Content = "Content 1"},
            new BookModel() {Title = "Title 2", Content = "Content 2"},
            new BookModel() {Title = "Title 3", Content = "Content 3"},
            new BookModel() {Title = "Title 4", Content = "Content 4"},
            new BookModel() {Title = "Title 5", Content = "Content 5"},
            new BookModel() {Title = "Title 6", Content = "Content 6"},
            new BookModel() {Title = "Title 7", Content = "Content 6"},
        };
    }
}

public class BookModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I see you have used static contents for "title" and "content" . If the title and contents were to be dynamic like in my case, how would I be able to mention the DisplayMemberPath. I am  confused. I ll keep researching more and get back with some more codes.